# Regular expression for url longer than 3 characters Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, regex

There is a website site.ru/
I need to write a regular expression where pages longer than 3 characters only work after the first slash. If in this case there are other pages after the slash, then 404 was returned. For example

```
site.ru/demo -> site.ru/demo
site.ru/dem/dem -> site.ru/dem/dem
site.ru/demo/{string of any length} -> 404
```

I wrote the following regular expression,

```
map $example {
            default 0;
            "~[^\/]\w.{3,}" 1;
}
```

but it works on both site.ru/demo and site.ru/demo/demo. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `/demo/demo` is probably a bad example, which one causes it to fail? `/demo/dem` or `/dem/demo`?

Comment: @Richard Smith added update: can be a string of any length

Comment: Try: "~^/\w{4,}/"

Comment: I don't know but this grabs urls; can be a good starting point I guess;  `"(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*"` `tested in bash`

Comment: Can you elaborate where the `$example` variable is used? That affects what has to be considered when writing the regex? Also, you can use https://regexr.com to play with the regular expressions.